# select columns from different tables with different types without using joins

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

Here's the situation I have a table 'teachers' whose columns are (tid, tname)
and I have a table 'students' whose columns are (sid,sname). Assuming they have  m:n  relationship, I have one more table t_s (tid,sid) where both tid and sid are referencing tid of teachers and sid of students respectively.
Now I want to find: The teachers name(with their tid's) and the number of students under each teacher.[without using Joins or cartesian product]

The following query returns me the count with tid :

```
SELECT t.tid, count(*) as numberofstudents
FROM t_s t
GROUPBY by t.tid;
```

How will I match the tname with the respective tid, tried with union:

```
SELECT t.tid, count(*) as numberofstudents
FROM t_s t
GROUP BY t.tid
UNION
SELECT t1.tid,t1.tname
FROM teachers t1
WHERE t1.tid in (SELECT t2.tid
                FROM t_s t2 )
```

Discovered that it doesn't work because the column types are different.

Is there a way to achieve it?
Thank you!

Comment: Why without joins?

Comment: The avoidance of JOINs is a little perverse.

Comment: is it purely presentational? You want a header row of the teacher name then their count underneath (rather than alongside)?

Comment: @MatthewCawley,thank you for your response.Without joins because 
It's sort of an assignment,and query output must be like : (tid,tname,numberofstundents),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also curious about why

> without using Joins or cartesian product

however, you can try this:

```
SELECT 
    t.tid,
    COUNT(*) as numberofstudents,
    (SELECT t1.tname FROM teachers t1 WHERE t1.tid = t.tid) AS tname
FROM t_s t
GROUP BY by t.tid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using dummy columns

```
SELECT t.tid, '' as teachername, count(*) as numberofstudents
FROM t_s t
GROUP BY t.tid
UNION
SELECT t1.tid,t1.tname, 0
FROM teachers t1
WHERE t1.tid in (SELECT t2.tid
                FROM t_s t2 )
```

Comment: Hey @P.Salmon i tried with it, but the result is unorganized

Comment: It would be. I suspect you need to wrap this in an outer query and then order by tid and number of students. If you want the teacher last then change 0 to a very high number in the teachers part of the query.